# Java implement priority queue using binary heap errors

Tags: java, arrays, string, priority-queue, binary-heap

I have a homework problem as follows:

Created HeapPriorityQueue that will implement Priority queue

```
import java.util.Arrays;  

public class HeapPriorityQueue<K,V extends Comparable<K>> implements PriorityQueue<K, V> {  
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;  
    protected K[] array;  
    protected int size;  

    /** 
     * Constructs a new BinaryHeap. 
     */  
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public HeapPriorityQueue() {  
        // Java doesn't allow construction of arrays of placeholder data types   
        array = (K[])new Comparable[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];    
        size = 0;  
    }  


    /** 
     * Adds a value to the min-heap. 
     */  
    public void add(K value) {  
        // grow array if needed  
        if (size >= array.length - 1) {  
            array = this.resize();  
        }          

        // place element into heap at bottom  
        size++;  
        int index = size;  
        array[index] = value;  

        bubbleUp();  
    }  

    /** 
     * Returns true if the heap has no elements; false otherwise. 
     */  
    public boolean isEmpty() {  
        return size == 0;  
    }  


    /** 
     * Returns (but does not remove) the minimum element in the heap. 
     */  
    public K peek() {  
        if (this.isEmpty()) {  
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Invalid Key");  
        }  

        return array[1];  
    }  


    /** 
     * Removes and returns the minimum element in the heap. 
     */  
    public K remove() {  
        // what do want return?  
        K result = peek();  

        // get rid of the last leaf/decrement  
        array[1] = array[size];  
        array[size] = null;  
        size--;  

        bubbleDown();  

        return result;  
    }  


    /** 
     * Returns a String representation of BinaryHeap with values stored with  
     * heap structure and order properties. 
     */  
    public String toString() {  
        return Arrays.toString(array);  
    }  


    /** 
     * Performs the "bubble down" operation to place the element that is at the  
     * root of the heap in its correct place so that the heap maintains the  
     * min-heap order property. 
     */  
    protected void bubbleDown() {  
        int index = 1;  

        // bubble down  
        while (hasLeftChild(index)) {  
            // which of my children is smaller?  
            int smallerChild = leftIndex(index);  

            // bubble with the smaller child, if I have a smaller child  
            if (hasRightChild(index)  
                && array[leftIndex(index)].compareTo(array[rightIndex(index)]) > 0) {  
                smallerChild = rightIndex(index);  
            }   

            if (array[index].compareTo(array[smallerChild]) > 0) {  
                swap(index, smallerChild);  
            } else {  
                // otherwise, get outta here!  
                break;  
            }  

            // make sure to update loop counter/index of where last el is put  
            index = smallerChild;  
        }          
    }  


    /** 
     * Performs the "bubble up" operation to place a newly inserted element  
     * (i.e. the element that is at the size index) in its correct place so  
     * that the heap maintains the min-heap order property. 
     */  
    protected void bubbleUp() {  
        int index = this.size;  

        while (hasParent(index)  
                && (parent(index).compareTo(array[index]) > 0)) {  
            // parent/child are out of order; swap them  
            swap(index, parentIndex(index));  
            index = parentIndex(index);  
        }          
    }  


    protected boolean hasParent(int i) {  
        return i > 1;  
    }  


    protected int leftIndex(int i) {  
        return i * 2;  
    }  


    protected int rightIndex(int i) {  
        return i * 2 + 1;  
    }  


    protected boolean hasLeftChild(int i) {  
        return leftIndex(i) <= size;  
    }  


    protected boolean hasRightChild(int i) {  
        return rightIndex(i) <= size;  
    }  


    protected K parent(int i) {  
        return array[parentIndex(i)];  
    }  


    protected int parentIndex(int i) {  
        return i / 2;  
    }  


    protected K[] resize() {  
        return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);  
    }  


    protected void swap(int index1, int index2) {  
        K tmp = array[index1];  
        array[index1] = array[index2];  
        array[index2] = tmp;          
    }  

    @Override  
    public int size() {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return 0;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Entry<K, V> max() throws EmptyPriorityQueueException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Entry<K, V> insert(K key, V value) throws InvalidKeyException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Entry<K, V> extractMax() throws EmptyPriorityQueueException {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

}
```

this should implement this PriorityQueue

```
/** 
 * Interface for the priority queue ADT 
 *  
 * K is the key of the entry stored in the priority queue and denotes the priority of the entry. 
 *  
 * V is the auxillary data of the entry 
 * @author bryann 
 * 
 */  
public interface PriorityQueue<K extends Comparable<K>,V> {  
    /** 
     * Returns the number of items in the priority queue 
     *  
     * @return number of items in the priority queue 
     */  
    public int size();  

    /** 
     * Returns whether the priority queue is empty. 
     *  
     * @return true if the priority queue is empty. Otherwise, false. 
     */  
    public boolean isEmpty();  

    /** 
     * Returns but does not remove an entry with maximum priority key 
     *   
     * @return entry that has the highest priority key 
     * @throws EmptyPriorityQueueException 
     */  
    public Entry<K,V> max() throws EmptyPriorityQueueException;  

    /** 
     * Inserts a key-value pair and returns the entry created. 
     *  
     * @param key priority key of the entry to be inserted 
     * @param value value of the entry to be inserted 
     * @return entry that was inserted into the priority queue 
     * @throws InvalidKeyException 
     */  
    public Entry<K,V> insert(K key, V value) throws InvalidKeyException;  

    /** 
     * Removes and returns an entry with maximum priority key 
     *  
     * @return entry that has the highest priority key 
     * @throws EmptyPriorityQueueException 
     */  
    public Entry<K,V> extractMax() throws EmptyPriorityQueueException;  
}
```

while the Driver class is this

```
public class HeapPriorityQueueDriver {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        PriorityQueue<Integer, String> queue = new HeapPriorityQueue<Integer, String>();  
        queue.insert(0, "Zero");  
        queue.insert(10, "Ten");  
        queue.insert(1, "One");  
        queue.insert(5, "Five");  
        queue.insert(3, "Three");  
        queue.insert(7, "Seven");  
        queue.insert(9, "Nine");  

        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {  
            System.out.println(queue.extractMax());  
        } // end while  
    } // end main  
}
```

the problems I get are

```
Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends Comparable<K>> of the type HeapPriorityQueue<K,V> HeapPriorityQueueDriver.java   /MP7/src/simon/mp7  line 6  
Java Problem 
Bound mismatch: The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<K>> of the type Entry<K,V> HeapPriorityQueue.java /MP7/src/simon/mp7   line 199    
Java Problem 
Bound mismatch: The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<K>> of the type Entry<K,V> HeapPriorityQueue.java /MP7/src/simon/mp7   line 193    
Java Problem 
Bound mismatch: The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<K>> of the type Entry<K,V> HeapPriorityQueue.java /MP7/src/simon/mp7   line 187    
Java Problem 
The method compareTo(K) is undefined for the type K HeapPriorityQueue.java  /MP7/src/simon/mp7  line 126    
Java Problem 
The method compareTo(K) is undefined for the type K HeapPriorityQueue.java  /MP7/src/simon/mp7  line 104    
Java Problem 
The method compareTo(K) is undefined for the type K HeapPriorityQueue.java  /MP7/src/simon/mp7  line 100    
Java Problem 
Bound mismatch: The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<K>> of the type PriorityQueue<K,V> HeapPriorityQueue.java  /MP7/src/simon/mp7  line 5  

the message in the console is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends Comparable<K>> of the type HeapPriorityQueue<K,V> 

at simon.mp7.HeapPriorityQueueDriver.main(HeapPriorityQueueDriver.java:6)
```

Comment: thank you for that eye-sore fix @benatespina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `HeapPriorityQueue<K,V extends Comparable<K>>`, but you try to use it as:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer, String> queue = new HeapPriorityQueue<Integer, String>();
```

But `String` doesn't `extends Comparable<Integer>` so it gives you compilation error.

Comment: V = a string value, I do not know how to apply comparable int to K while having the V for string sir.

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you need V extends Comparable<K>?

Comment: I mean, such as in 
PriorityQueue<K extends Comparable<K>,V>
The V is still there, because I have to out put the int or the number into the word of the number
 queue.insert(0, "Zero");

Comment: So why dont you use <K extends Comparable<K>,V>?

Comment: That worked! thank you! umm, if you dont mind me asking, why is it when i run the program there is no output at all?

Comment: You can add some debug info and try to understand it. You can check for example what happens inside isEmpty

Comment: any other hints would be great sir! sorry for the bother but my homework is due in less than 2 hours :) and thank you for all the help so far

Comment: You need to implement insert(K key, V value). Currently it just returns null.

Comment: I couldn't get how to implement the insert(K,V) :(